# Unity3D - Start() being called on keypress?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

In the `Start()` function of my code i have code that saves the transform of two cubes into a transform arrays (in the start, everything is saved fine). However when i am setting the saved transforms in the update function, both positions transformArray[0] and transformArray[1] have the same value! why is this happening? I thought the Start function only ran once?

The start function seems to be called every time i press X (my key event), why is this happening? Im not telling it to run the Start() function in my code.

```
 Vector3 BoxPos;
 public GameObject box1;
 public GameObject box2;
 Transform targetTransform;
 public string curName;
 public Transform[] transformArray;

 void Start(){
     curName = gameObject.name;
     transformArray = new Transform[2];

     transformArray[0] = box1.GetComponent<Transform>();
     transformArray[1] = box2.GetComponent<Transform>();

     Debug.Log ("@Box1:" + transformArray[0].position); // VALUE IS PROPER
     Debug.Log ("@Box2:" + transformArray[1].position); // VALUE IS PROPER
 }

 void Update(){

     if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X)) {

     if(curName == "box1"){
         Debug.Log("&Box1:" + transformArray[1].position); //value=transformArray[1].position!
         targetTransform = transformArray[1];
     }else if(curName == "box2"){
         Debug.Log("&Box2:" + transformArray[0].position);//value=transformArray[1].position!
         targetTransform = transformArray[0];
     }

     BoxPos = targetTransform.position;
     transform.position = BoxPos;
     }
```

}

Comment: **"Start() being called on keypress"** from the code you posted, this sentence is false. Understand that `@Box1` and `@Box2` will be printed in the `Start()` function while `&Box1` and `&Box2` are called in the `Update` function. Verify that this is actually what's happening and make sure you don't have a code that reloads revel anywhere in your scene.

Comment: Yes that is intentional, it shows that `@Box1` and `@Box2` have the correct values but once the keypress event occurs the values changed which is shown through &Box1 and 2 EDIT: the problem could be that i have this script on both boxes but its suppose to be design around that anyways so i don't know

Comment: There is other relevant code to show ? transforArray is public, is accessed or manipulated from another script ?